# Loading Queue dynamically

Tags: configuration, jms, jboss7.x, message-queue

I'm implementing a Stateless Session Bean that sends messages to different messages queues. Currently to two different queues, but the number could be growing.

At the moment the queues are hard coded:

```
@Stateless
public class SendNotificationBean implements SendNotification {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SendNotificationBean.class);

  @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/MQ.CONNECTIONFACTORY.JMS.A")
  private ConnectionFactory connectionFactoryA;

  @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/MQ.CONNECTIONFACTORY.JMS.B")
  private ConnectionFactory connectionFactoryB;

  @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/MQ.A")
  private Queue queueA;

  @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/MQ.B")
  private Queue queueB;

  private Connection connectionA;
  private Connection connectionB;

  private MessageProducer producerA;
  private MessageProducer producerB;

  private Session sessionA;
  private Session sessionB;

  //...

}
```

Would it be possible to load the queue dynamically? Something like:

```
Queue queue = getQueueDependingOfConfiguration(QueueType.A);
```

I think it's possible, but does it also make sense? And what do I have to consider? Do I then have to store the ConnectionFactory and/or Session in a Map?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the good old JNDI InitialContext lookup:

```
public Queue getQueueByName(String name) {
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    return ctx.lookup("java:jboss/MQ." + name);
}
```

The same could be done for QueueConnectionFactory.
However, this approach has its own drawbacks, as the proper way to deal with JNDI objects is to add it into component JNDI environment (java:comp/env stuff).

Storing QueueConnectionFactory or Queue instances in Map is not advisable - you are on the safe side if you get references to these objects whenever you need it.